# Laravel 8 route returning fail, the post method works fine but the get method is not reaching to controller?

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-8

**These are controllers**

```
Route::post('user/project', [UserProjectsController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('user/projects', [UserProjectsController::class, 'index']);
```

> these are the routes

[image: this is the response, it is not returning any error]

Comment: show us the error message, fail message

Comment: show us also controller code, especially index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a 200 HTTP Response. That means that your request pass the route and would probably pass the controller. *It depends where you redirect the request from your route*. I assume the controller now.

look at the called method in the corresponding controller.  Search for the word `fail`. You have find one condition which checks something.

```php
if (condition) {
return ['result' => 'fail'];
```

When you have found the passage, look at it and check the algorithm why it does not pass the condition.

### UPDATE

Modelnames are singular and not plural.
`UserProject::all` instead `UserProjects`

Comment: thanks alot, but there is no condition for `return ['result' => 'fail'];` , i am only using try catch        
 `    public function index()
    {
        try {
            $project = UserProjects::all();
            return response()->json(['result' => 'success', 'project' => $project]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }  
    }`

Comment: @MUHAMMADFAIZ Ok. I didn't know your method. Then the following happened. Something went wrong in your Request:all() request. Probably it did not know the model.Try with Laravel 8: `App\Models\UserProject::all()` and with Laravel < 8 `App\UserProject::all()` .

Comment: @MUHAMMADFAIZ i udated my answer. UserProject::all instead UserProjects